# Was a massive case of voter fraud uncovered in Florida?

Tags: united-states, politics

Dennis Michel Lynch's website has [a report](http://dennismichaellynch.com/florida-election-officials-busted-massive-voter-fraud/) that election officials for the Broward County Supervisor of Elections (SOE) in Florida were seen fraudulently filling in absentee votes.

An affidavit of the witness (Chelsey Marie Smith) was presented.

> Through the thin window in the door, Smith said she could see four SOE employees sitting at a table with stacks of documents, writing something.   Eventually one person came to the door, took the ballots, and closed the door, without letting her inside.
>
> Later, she was asked to deliver another stack of absentee ballot request forms to the same room, where the same four people were still writing something on the documents.   This time she was hurriedly allowed inside the room and told to put the ballots on a different table.  She was able to see that the employees were filling in bubbles on the ballots, moving the completed ballots to a new stack.  She said she witnessed this happening for over a minute before being told to leave the room.

This message was also presented discussed on the [USMEssageBoard](http://www.usmessageboard.com/threads/florida-election-officials-busted-for-massive-voter-fraud.544288/#post-15738611).

Is this true? Can this be verified?

Comment: Reminds me of this; http://metro.co.uk/2014/09/19/scottish-independence-video-proves-vote-was-rigged-say-yes-voters-4874786/

Comment: And of [this](http://www.gregpalast.com/floridas-flawed-voter-cleansing-program-saloncoms-politics-story-of-the-year/), and [this](http://www.gregpalast.com/rolling-stone-expose-gops-secret-plan-steal-vote/), and [this](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/law-and-order/11560017/Postal-voting-fraud-is-easy-electoral-commissioner-says.html).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

This is an ongoing court case so this question cannot be conclusively answered right now. However, the district attorney does have an explanation that they've been providing to reporters. ([Source](http://ijr.com/opinion/2016/11/261634-florida-voter-fraud-broward-county/))

> It was determined that the ballots were being completed by SOE staff on behalf of overseas military personnel who had voted by faxing their ballots to the election office. The fax paper does not scan into the voting machines and the votes must be transferred onto a ballot that can be scanned. State law allows such a transfer of vote to a computer ballot.

Comment: The title to that article contains the word 'Democrat', but neither the body nor the affidavit itself mention who they were alleged to be voting for. Perhaps (I'm not from the US) that is somehow meant to be evident from the context but I think it's worth pointing out it's not there.

Comment: @abligh The rumor was being spread by Trump supporters. Currently in the US, Trump supporters frequently allege voter fraud by authorities, while Clinton supporters allege voter intimidation and denial of voting rights. So, the word "Democrat" is a normal part of a rumor like this.